# Substitute text in a file by value from hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a perl hash that looks like this:

```
{
  "case1"   => 0.05,
  "case2"   => 0.105,
  "case3"   => -0.006,
  "case4"   => -0.0005,
  "case5"   => 0.0501,
  "case6"   => 0.098,
  "case7"   => 0.16,
}
```

How can I use hash's key to replace matching key in a text with a value.
Text file example:

```
 set case1
 set case5
 set case3
 set case4
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a regex from the keys

```
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %hash;
```

Then use it to substitute

```
s/($regex)/$hash{$1}/g;
```

When the keys are of different length, you might need to sort them longest first before creating the regex.

So, a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = (
    case1 => 0.05,
    case2 => 0.105,
    case3 => -0.006,
    case4 => -0.0005,
    case5 => 0.0501,
);

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    s/($regex)/$hash{$1}/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
 set case1
 set case5
 set case3
 set case4
```

Answer (score 0):

Desired result obtained with a little bit different code

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %hash = (
    case1 => 0.05,
    case2 => 0.105,
    case3 => -0.006,
    case4 => -0.0005,
    case5 => 0.0501,
);

my @data = <DATA>;

chomp @data;

@data = map { s/(case\d)/$hash{$1}/ && $_ } @data;

say for @data;

__DATA__
set case1
set case5
set case3
set case4
```

Output

```
set 0.05
set 0.0501
set -0.006
set -0.0005
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if order of lines is significant following code preserves it

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %hash = (
    case1 => 0.05,
    case2 => 0.105,
    case3 => -0.006,
    case4 => -0.0005,
    case5 => 0.0501,
);

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

for my $k(keys %hash) {
    $data =~ s/$k/$hash{$k}/g;
}

say $data;

__DATA__
set case1
set case5
set case3
set case4
```

Output

```
set 0.05
set 0.0501
set -0.006
set -0.0005
```